# How does RSpec know if a password is less than the intended length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial, and the Rspec section has been confusing.  I already tried reading other free materials out there such as nets tuts.  Anyway, in one of his blocks, here's an excerpt:

```
describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end
```

I understand that if the length happens to be 5 characters, the password would be invalid.  But how would it know if the password is less than 5?

PS. (If you need to see more of the spec, [here's the link](http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-authenticate_spec))

Answer (score 1):

RSpec doesn't know that.. it check if it's valid for particular model. You define at model how long it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

I expect at the top of this spec you have code like:

```
before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "mysecret", password_confirmation: "mysecret" }

subject { @user }
```

What that's doing is creating a new user and then making the `@user` instance the *subject* of the tests.

When you reach this specific password length test you are first setting the password to a 5 character string and then assert that the password is now invalid.

Behind the scenes `subject` in conjunction with `it { should be_invalid }` is effectively doing a `@user.valid?` and expecting it to fail due to the length validation on the password field.  Hence the test passes.

You are using rspec here to ensure that there is good password length validation on the user model.  You can prove your test is not a false positive by changing to a 6 character password.  Again rspec will do a `@user.valid?` but this time the test should fail because the user record is valid however the test expects it not to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [section 6.3.4](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#sec-has_secure_password) you see that the author adds the validation on `User` model so your test passes.

> As a result, we’ll complete the implementation of secure passwords (and get to a green test suite) using only a few lines of code.
>
> First, we need a length validation for the password, which uses the :minimum key in analogy with the :maximum key from Listing 6.12:
>
> `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }`
>
> (Presence validations for the password and its confirmation are automatically added by has_secure_password.)